# Metsploit installation: could not find mini_portile2 - 2.8.0 in any of the sources

Tags: rubygems, ubuntu-20.04, metasploit

I recently installed metasploit on my Ubuntu 20.04 VM.
I ran `sudo bundler install`
It finishes successfully.
Then I ran `./msfconsole`.
It says >*could not find mini_portile2 - 2.8.0 in any of the sources. Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems*.

What can I do about this please

Comment: ⚠️️ This sounds off-topic for this site. Please kindly read [this Help Center page](/help/on-topic) to learn what's on-topic here. See also: ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask) If you're not sure where to ask this question, you can ask on [meta.se] using the \[site-recommendation\] tag.

Comment: So, problems installing dependencies of code I'm working on is not about software tools used by programmers and therefore unwelcome on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

The right command to install missing `portile2` dependency:

```bash
gem install mini_portile2 -v 2.8.0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo gem install mini_portile2
```

Should help

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.